# Unable to assign values to an array

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

Look at this piece of code.. 
In this I am taking input from a file and assigning to an array *sudoku[][]*.. and simultaneously assigning those values to *TempArr[][]* (another array)..

But when I checked the values of TempArr[][] after assigning, there aren't same as in sudoku[][].

```
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
        if(fscanf(ip_file,"%d",&sudoku[i][j])==1)
        {         
                  //copy to TempArr
                  TempArr[i][j]==sudoku[i][j];
        }
        else
        {
            perror ("fscanf failed on input file.\n");
            // return error
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I replaced "sudoku[][]" with "TempArr[][]", its working..
i.e.,     `if(fscanf(ip_file,"%d",&TempArr[i][j])==1)`

Why this is happening and how do I handle this situation ?

Comment: Don't you get an *expression has no effect* kind of warning for that?

Comment: @K-ballo - it does if you're using `-Wunused-value` (or `-Wall`) with gcc, but otherwise ... not so much. However, it's a good point to make - thanks, editing.

Answer (score 5):

```
TempArr[i][j]==sudoku[i][j];
```

See the `==` ? That wouldn't be assigning ;)

**Edit:** Also worth noting - the compiler can help you with these things. If you use the `-Wall` option when compiling, it will tell you:

> > gcc -Wall -o test test.c
>   test.c:13:9: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]

There's a number of helpful warning levels you can specify to alert you of these things:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't looking at that small mistake

Comment: Should there not be a warning for comparisons where the result is ignored?  I'm sure I got one last time I did this on gcc.  It's such a common error, (we've all done it), that there should be a warning.

Comment: Some compilers warn of a result with no side-effect or use.  And Java will not let you do the opposite (use `=` instead of `==`) due to the way they type the values.

Comment: Not unless you specifically ask for them. It's a good point to make though, so I've added that to my answer.

Comment: I didn't get any warning. I'm using Mingw

Answer (score 1):

Uh, `==` isn't assignment, it's a test for equality.

Comment: (I've made the same mistake more than once -- probably more often than I've tried to use `=` for comparison.)

Comment: I loath admitting it, but same here.